# Google Cloud Platform Windows Virtual Machine Problem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In Google Cloud Platform on my Windows Virtual Machine I can't download the Opera Browser and get a message that says:

> Your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded

And I can't press certain buttons on some websites.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

1.Click on Server Manager.

2.Local Server.

3.Please check your IE Enhanced Security Configuration.

4.Do a test by turning it off.

5.Reactivate after download if need be.